# Access dynamically created objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am attempting to dynamically create an object with name-value pairs using html input fields. This is what i have so far:

```
var taskComplete = {
  newTask: function(arg) {
    var fieldObj = {},
        selector = arg,
        inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);          
    for (var i=0;i<inputFields.length;i++) {
      var attrValue = inputFields[i].getAttribute("name"),
          value = inputFields[i].value, 
          newFieldObj = fieldObj[i] = {[attrValue]: value };
      console.log(newFieldObj);             
    }      
  }
}
taskComplete.newTask('input');
```

**The console log outputs:**

```
Object {title: ""}
Object {description: ""}
Object {date: ""}
```

**Question1:**
How do i access these objects? they all share the same name eg. 'Object' so 'object.title' does not work.

**Question2:**
Is there a way to combine these objects into a single object? 
eg.

```
var obj = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  date: "",
}
```

code example with html: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/vGNxRE)

**Hope this make sense. Thank you for any and all assistance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your questions in the reverse order, makes more sense, you will see.

> Question2: Is there a way to combine these objects into a single object?

Yes, I am happy to inform you that you absolutely can. Where you do

```
newFieldObj = fieldObj[i] = {[attrValue]: value };
```

simply do

```
fieldObj[attrValue] = value;
```

What this does, is the following: On the  `fieldObj`, which is a plain `{}` set a key named after the value of `attrValue` and pair that key with the value `value`

> Question1: How do i access these objects? they all share the same name eg. 'Object' so 'object.title' does not work.

In order to be able to access these objects, your `newTask` method should be *returning* them. So, at the end of your `newTask` method, simply do `return fieldObj;` like so

```
var taskComplete = {
  newTask: function(arg) {
    var fieldObj = {},
        selector = arg,
        inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName(selector),
        attrValue,
        value;

    for (var i=0;i<inputFields.length;i++) {
      attrValue = inputFields[i].getAttribute("name");
      value = inputFields[i].value;
      fieldObj[attrValue] = value;     
    }      
    return fieldObj;
  }
}
```

and then store the returned value to a new variable like so:

```
var aFancyName = taskComplete.newTask('input');
```

Here's the modified pen: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdjKQJ**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I made the changes to the newTask() functiion, which now returns the objects. However i am still a bit unclear as to how i access them. Using your example, would i acces  objects like this? eks: aFancyName.title, aFancyName.description, aFancyName.date. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you access them! If you found my answer helpful and resolved your question consider marking it as an accepted answer.

Comment: lol i kept trying "console.log(aFancyName.title) wich only returned  a empty line in the console. Took me a few min to realize it was because the object property was missing a value. Thank you so much for you help and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Not super clear on what you are trying to do here.

Instead of creating a new object for each iteration of your loop, why not just assign those properties to the fieldObj you already have?

Then you can just return that object and do whatever you want with it in the calling code:

```
'use strict';

// ** TASK OBJECT ** //
var taskComplete = {
  newTask: function(selector) {
    var fieldObj = {},
        inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);

    for (var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
      var attrKey = inputFields[i].getAttribute("name"),
          value = inputFields[i].value;

      fieldObj[attrKey] = value;
    }

    return fieldObj;
  }
}
var o = taskComplete.newTask('input');
console.dir(o);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reMLPB?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you for you response. I sorry if my description was difficult to understand. You figured it out though and your response was just what i needed!